# Raspberry Pi lose network

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have a raspberry pi 2 connected to a lan. Sometimes the raspberry loses the network connectivity. After unplug and re-plug the network cable in the router the network on the raspberry turns to work. I have the RASPBIAN JESSIE installed.
Has someone a idea?

Answer (score 1):

See what `/var/log/syslog` says when that happens.  Whether you are using wired or wireless, if you start getting errors about its built-in ethernet, that can also interrupt anything else on USB. Installing all updates - regular updates did NOT help: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y`

What could help is doing `rpi-update`.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check your modem port settings if speed is auto, full duplex. Then you can check the RPi side and also you can try to set 100full statically.

Did you try to replace your network cable?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure the power cable , replace a better power cable might help. I had this experience and it worked by doing so.